Is there a way to make Android/iOS camera scan a QR Code that contains HTML and it opens in browser without internet?
I would like to create a QR Code containing HTML that a person uses its Android/iOS camera to click in the Scanned QR Code through their camera and it opens an offline HTML (the HTML code  is already in the QR Code content) without internet requirement.
Like it access a localhost page in their own phone with the HTML inside
For example: the content of the QR Code is: "Hello this is an offline content opened through the QR Code" and it shows in their default browser without internet
How can I do that?

A typical QR code scanner app on iOS/Android won't know that the contents of the QR code are to be interpreted as HTML. The trick is not packing HTML into a QR code (a payload in a QR code is just a sequence of bytes).

On a side note, it would be a giant attack vector for malware.

Both platforms have a camera, there are QR code reading libraries and a WebView that can load HTML code if you supply it (from the QR code reading library). So I don't see the point in your question.

Do realize that each platform default camera has a number of 'default' string format that do something, see: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents That doesn't mean every QR code reader will follow that convention OR any QR code reader will extend it with their own custom string format (inventory / game data / etc.)

QR Code doesn’t have enough space to contain a html file.
But you can transfer html file through dynamic QR Code via camera.
Once it is done, render the html file content via WebView.
See these projects for more detail:
LucaIaco/QRFileTransfer
sz3/libcimbar
